# Having trouble using import in java

Tags: java

I'm attempting to compile some code starting with the line:

```
import java.util.*;
```

and I keep getting the error:

```
class, interface, or enum expected
```

I've seen on other post that this is because I'm not using import correctly.  Do I need to set it up somehow, like when I added a PATH exception for java in the first place.  I'm kind of having a rough time figuring this out.  I'm pretty sure the code is good besides this.

```
import java.util.*;

public class setUpGame {

        private ArrayList<Weapon> weaponArray = new ArrayList<Weapon>();

        class Weapon{
            private String name = null; 
            private String description = null;
            private int damageBase;

            public String getName(){
                return name;
            }
            public void setName(String n){
                name = n;
            }
            public String getDescription(){
                return description;
            }
            public void setDescription(String d){
                description = d;
            }
            public int getDamageBase(){
                    return damageBase;
            }
            public void setDamageBase(int d){
                damageBase = d;
            }
        }//END class Weapon

        Weapon spear = new Weapon();
        spear.setName("Mighty Spear");
        spear.setDescription("An ancient spear. Bronze of tip, ash of shaft, decorated in slivers or roc's feather.");
        spear.setDamageBase(3);

        Weapon hooks = new Weapon();
        hooks.setName("Silver Hooks");
        hooks.setDescription("A pair of sharp, hand-held fighting hooks. Obsidian core, plated in silver.");
        hooks.setDamageBase(2);

        Weapon flameSword = new Weapon();
        sword.setName("Flamesake");
        sword.setDescription("An arming sword, newly enchanted.  It erupts in flame when removed from the scabbard.");
        sword.setDamageBase(3);

        Weapon scissors = new Weapon();
        scissors.setName("Snippy");
        scissors.setDescription("Your mother's sewing scissors. They are nearly two hands long, as she was a large woman.");
        scissors.setDamageBase(1);

        Weapon darkGun = new Weapon();
        darkGun.setName("Dark Cannon");
        darkGun.setDescription("A finely crafted hand cannon.  It has been enchanted by a dark sorcerer to fire bolts of corrupting darkness.");
        darkGun.setDamageBase(3);

        Weapon iceBow = new Weapon();
        iceBow.setName("Chilling Bow");
        iceBow.setDescription("");
        iceBow.setDamageBase(2);

        weaponArray.add(spear);
        weaponArray.add(hooks);
        weaponArray.add(flameSword);
        weaponArray.add(scissors);
        weaponArray.add(darkGun);
        weaponArray.add(iceBow);



        // set up game flavor text
    }

public class SetUpGameTestDrive(){
    public static void main(String [] args){
        for (Weapon currentWeapon : weaponArray){
            System.out.println(currentWeapon.getName() + "is " + currentWeapon.getDescription() + "It has a damage base of " +
            currentWeapon.getDamageBase() + ".");
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the relevant code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looks like you left out the `.`, should be `import java.util.*;`

Comment: Is the import at the top of the file, preceded only by a "package" statement?  Ah - I think Shafik spotted it!

Comment: I don't have a package statement.  Edited the OP with the code.

Comment: The new code does not compile as posted and does not produce the original error in the question, so it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: OK i think I broke something.  Thanks for your help everyone, I'll come back when this thing's not so broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be `import java.util.*;`
What this statement means is include ALL the types those are present in `java.util` package.

If you want to include only specific type then you can use fully qualified name e.g. `java.util.Calendar`. This will include only the `Calendar` class.

There is a common misconception that `import` statement is used to include the required types to use in the code but that is not completely true. It just enables us to use the short name instead of its fully qualified name.

You can still use

```
package com.so;

public class ImportTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println(date);

    }

}
```

This will compile fine and print current date. The `import` statement just enables us to use short names for the types.

so when you use import statement then code becomes.

package com.so;

```
import java.util.Date;

public class ImportTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date);

    }

}
```

Comment: That was a typo here in the post.  I did use java.util.*;  And even tried using: import java.util.ArrayList; which is the one that I'm actually trying to use, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @JavaNoob can you please post full code?

Comment: This is not really an answer anymore since it is not clear what the real problem is.